# Gradient based on mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, colors, mouse-coordinates

The below code creates a gradient that changes with the location of the cursor, which is what I want, but the colors seem very limited and not always what I'm looking for. Is there a way to set this up to ensure the colors stay in lighter and more saturated tones? Also, I'd like to have more contrast between the two sides, as you can see, they sometimes become the same color.

I know the math that I have is quite obviously not set up for this but I'm not knowledgeable enough on the structure of hexadecimal colors to know where to go from here.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    top = [],
    bottom = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };
$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {
    top = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        150
    ];

     bottom = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/h * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/w * 255),
        150
    ];
    $(document.body).css({background : '-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb('+top.join(',')+'), rgb('+bottom.join(',')+'))'});
    $(document.body).css({background : '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb('+top.join(',')+'), rgb('+bottom.join(',')+'))'});
}).resize();
});
```

Comment: That’s a bit of a vague description, but try using `hsl` notation instead of `rgb`.

Comment: That just causes a white page

Comment: Well, look up HSL notation, first… you can’t just replace `rgb` with `hsl`, you need to use one angle and two percentages instead of three bytes.